# Error al ejecutar Prodecure - Tipos de datos GEOMETRY - SQL SERVER 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

Buenas tardes,

Arme un Procedure que verifica si un punto esta dentro o fuera de un Poligono.

Tengo una tabla de poligonos y una tabla de puntos (Float)

Hago todas las conversiones debidas.

Para poder realizarlo, utilice los tipos de datos GOEMETRY.

Cuando ejecuto el Procedure, ejecuta correctamente hasta un determnado punto donde me da el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Utilizo de esta forma los datos Geometricos:

```
DECLARE @ArrayPtosEncontrados GEOMETRY;
DECLARE @Puntos GEOMETRY;

SET @ArrayPtosEncontrados = GEOMETRY::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING('+@ArrayPtosPoligono+')', 0)

SET @Puntos = GEOMETRY::STGeomFromText('POINT('+REPLACE(FORMAT(@LatitudPto,'G'),',','.')+' '+REPLACE(FORMAT(@LongitudPto,'G'),',','.') +')', 0)
```

Agrego un ejemplo completo:

```
USE [BASE]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[GeoUbicacion]    Script Date: 13/12/2017 10:15:16 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GeoUbicacion] AS 

DECLARE PUNTOS CURSOR FOR
SELECT LATITUD,LONGITUD FROM Automatizacion.dbo.geo_Puntos

DECLARE POLIGONOS CURSOR STATIC SCROLL FOR
SELECT NOMBRE_AREA,LATITUD, LONGITUD FROM Automatizacion.dbo.geo_Poligonos
ORDER BY NOMBRE_AREA,ORDEN


BEGIN TRY

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @ArrayPtosEncontrados GEOMETRY;
DECLARE @ArrayPtosEncontrados2 GEOMETRY;
DECLARE @Puntos GEOMETRY;
DECLARE @PuntoPoligonoLat float;
DECLARE @PuntoPoligonoLon float;
DECLARE @NombrePoligono varchar(30);
DECLARE @Orden int;
DECLARE @Area varchar(30);
DECLARE @PrimerLat float;
DECLARE @PrimerLon float;
DECLARE @ArrayPtosPoligono VARCHAR(2000);
DECLARE @Primero int;
DECLARE @LatitudPto float;
DECLARE @LongitudPto float;
DECLARE @Pertenece varchar(2);
DECLARE @mensajeError VARCHAR(2000);
DECLARE @Diferente int;



    --// SE ABRE EL CURSOR DE POLIGONOS \\--

    OPEN POLIGONOS;

    --// POR CADA AREA DEL POLIGONO SE VERIFICA SI EL PUNTO PERTENECE A ELLA \\--

    --// SE TOMA EL PRIMER REGISTRO Y SE GUARDA EL AREA \\--

    FETCH NEXT FROM POLIGONOS INTO @NombrePoligono, @PuntoPoligonoLat, @PuntoPoligonoLon;


    --// SE GUARDA EL PRIMER PUNTO PARA LUEGO AGREGARLO AL FINAL Y PODER CERRAR EL POLIGONO \\--

    SET @PrimerLat = @PuntoPoligonoLat
    SET @PrimerLon = @PuntoPoligonoLon

    SET @ArrayPtosPoligono = REPLACE(FORMAT(@PrimerLat,'G'),',','.')+' '+REPLACE(FORMAT(@PrimerLon,'G'),',','.')+','
    SET @Primero = 0;
    SET @Diferente = 0


    WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    BEGIN

        --// SE GUARDA EL AREA PARA EL CORTE DE CONTROL \\--

        SET @Area = @NombrePoligono;

        --// MIENTRAS SIGA LA MISMA AREA, SE AGREGA LOS PUNTOS DEL POLIGONO \\--

        WHILE (@Area = @NombrePoligono)
        BEGIN

             if (@Primero = 0)
             BEGIN

                  --// SE VUELVE A SETEAR EL PRIMER REGISTRO PARA EL NUEVO POLIGONO \\--

                  SET @PrimerLat = @PuntoPoligonoLat
                  SET @PrimerLon = @PuntoPoligonoLon
                  SET @ArrayPtosPoligono = null
                  SET @ArrayPtosPoligono = REPLACE(FORMAT(@PrimerLat,'G'),',','.')+' '+REPLACE(FORMAT(@PrimerLon,'G'),',','.')+','                

                  SET @ArrayPtosPoligono = @ArrayPtosPoligono
                  SET @Primero = 1
             END
             ELSE
             BEGIN

                  SET @ArrayPtosPoligono = @ArrayPtosPoligono + REPLACE(FORMAT(@PuntoPoligonoLat,'G'),',','.')+' '+REPLACE(FORMAT(@PuntoPoligonoLon,'G'),',','.')+','

             END

             IF @Area <> @NombrePoligono or @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0
             BEGIN
                BREAK
             END
             ELSE
             BEGIN

                FETCH NEXT FROM POLIGONOS INTO @NombrePoligono, @PuntoPoligonoLat, @PuntoPoligonoLon;               

                IF (@Area <> @NombrePoligono)
                BEGIN
                    BREAK;
                END

             END             

        END;

        SET @Primero = 0

        --// SE AGREGA EL PRIMER PUNTO PARA CERRAR EL POLIGONO \\--

        SET @ArrayPtosPoligono = @ArrayPtosPoligono + REPLACE(FORMAT(@PrimerLat,'G'),',','.')+' '+REPLACE(FORMAT(@PrimerLon,'G'),',','.')

        --// TODOS LOS PUNTOS PARA UN AREA DETERMINADA \\--

        SET @ArrayPtosEncontrados = GEOMETRY::STGeomFromText('POLYGON(('+@ArrayPtosPoligono+'))', 0)
        SET @ArrayPtosEncontrados2 = GEOMETRY::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING('+@ArrayPtosPoligono+')', 0)

        PRINT 'POLIGONO: ' + @ArrayPtosPoligono

        --//  SE INSERTA EN TABLA TODOS LOS PUNTOS DEL POLIGONO RECORRIENDO EL CURSOR DE PUNTOS \\--

        --// SE ABRE EL CURSOR DE PUNTOS \\--


        OPEN PUNTOS;        

        FETCH PUNTOS INTO @LatitudPto, @LongitudPto;

            WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
            BEGIN

                SET @Puntos = GEOMETRY::STGeomFromText('POINT('+REPLACE(FORMAT(@LatitudPto,'G'),',','.')+' '+REPLACE(FORMAT(@LongitudPto,'G'),',','.') +')', 0)

                --// VERIFICA LOS PUNTOS QUE ESTAN EN EL POLIGONO \\--

                IF ((SELECT @ArrayPtosEncontrados2.STIntersects(@Puntos)) = 1)
                BEGIN
                    SET @Pertenece = 'SI'
                END
                ELSE
                BEGIN
                    SET @Pertenece = 'NO'
                END

                IF ((SELECT @ArrayPtosEncontrados.STContains(@Puntos)) = 1 and @Pertenece = 'NO')
                BEGIN
                    SET @Pertenece = 'SI'
                END
                ELSE
                BEGIN
                    SET @Pertenece = 'NO'
                END

                INSERT INTO dbo.GEO_Puntos_Poligonos (Nombre_Area,PuntosPoligono,PuntoX,PuntoY,PertenecePoligono)
                VALUES (@Area,@ArrayPtosPoligono,REPLACE(FORMAT(@LatitudPto,'G'),',','.'),REPLACE(FORMAT(@LongitudPto,'G'),',','.'),@Pertenece)

                FETCH PUNTOS INTO @LatitudPto, @LongitudPto;

            END;

        CLOSE PUNTOS

            FETCH PRIOR FROM POLIGONOS INTO @NombrePoligono, @PuntoPoligonoLat, @PuntoPoligonoLon;
            FETCH NEXT FROM POLIGONOS INTO @NombrePoligono, @PuntoPoligonoLat, @PuntoPoligonoLon;


    END

--// SE CIERRA EL CURSOR DE POLIGONOS Y SE LIBERA LA MEMORIA \\--

CLOSE POLIGONOS
DEALLOCATE POLIGONOS

--// SE CIERRA EL CURSOR DE PUNTOS Y SE LIBERA LA MEMORIA \\--

CLOSE PUNTOS
DEALLOCATE PUNTOS

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

        SELECT @mensajeError = ERROR_MESSAGE();

        PRINT 'SE PRODUJO EL SIGUIENTE ERROR: ' + @mensajeError

        --// SE CIERRA EL CURSOR DE POLIGONOS Y SE LIBERA LA MEMORIA \\--

        CLOSE POLIGONOS
        DEALLOCATE POLIGONOS

        --// SE CIERRA EL CURSOR DE PUNTOS Y SE LIBERA LA MEMORIA \\--

        CLOSE PUNTOS
        DEALLOCATE PUNTOS

END CATCH

ACLARACION:Si no agrego:
 FETCH PRIOR FROM POLIGONOS INTO @NombrePoligono, @PuntoPoligonoLat, @PuntoPoligonoLon;
        FETCH NEXT FROM POLIGONOS INTO @NombrePoligono, @PuntoPoligonoLat, @PuntoPoligonoLon;
```

Al final del Bucle, pierdo un registro.

Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Sería una buena idea incluir un [mcve].

Comment: El error pareciera ser un problema de parsing, alguna definición de geometria mal construida. Lamentablemente como dice sstan, sin estos datos no podemos ayudarte.

Comment: Al parecer estas pasando un ) en ves de un numero como lo dice el error verifica la entrada que le estas dando al procedimiento.

Comment: Adjunto un ejemplo completo:

Comment: Hola @Osky. La idea de un [mcve] es que podamos copiar el script y reproducir tu error. En este caso, eso no se puede hacer, porque el script incluye referencias a objetos que desconocemos su definición. Adicionalmente, aunque lo mas importante es que el script sea completo, también es buena idea reducir el script hasta aíslar el problema de modo que el script llegue a ser lo *mínimo* necesario para reproducir el error, para evitar distracciones con código que no es relevante a tu problema.

Comment: Creo que el problema por lo que voy viendo, es que un poligono tiene 244 puntos, y cada punto es un String de 24 (longitud+' '+Latitud), eso me da un valor de 5856 bytes, si bien tengo declarado un varchar(8000) y deberia entrar, creo que al aplicar a cada punto un format a string, se modifica lo que ocupa cada punto y se corta en medio. No se que tipo de dato utilizar que sea mas grande que un varchar de (8000), ya que ese valor es el máximo. Alguna idea? @sstan

Comment: Tal vez un `varchar(max)`?

Comment: Ya lo probe y no funciona

Answer (score 0):

Buenas tardes,

El problema estaba en la capacidad del campo en donde insertaba el String donde iba el poligono. Al darle mas bytes a ese campo en la tabla, se soluciono el problema.

Gracias a todos por sus opiniones.

Osky

Comment: Por favor recuerda [aceptar tu propia respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Saludos.